# how to apply a mean filter on image in matlab

Tags: matlab, filter

I try to apply a mean filter on my image with this code:

```
 filtered1(:,:,1)= imfilter(double(image_input_R), ones(3,3) / 9, 'replicate');
filtered1(:,:,2)= imfilter(double(image_input_G), ones(3,3) / 9, 'replicate');
filtered1(:,:,3)= imfilter(double(image_input_B), ones(3,3) / 9, 'replicate');
figure,imshow(uint8(filtered1));
```

than i get a black image as result og this filter, what's wrong with my code??

I get to same result with filter `filter2`

Comment: multiply it by 255

Comment: thank you for your feedback, do you mean that filtered1=filtered1*255; I do that and I get a white image

Comment: What is the range of `filtered1` before you cast it to `uint8`?

Comment: Also, there's no need to do each channel separately. That's what `imfilter` is for.

Comment: you are right, with imfilter we don't need to separate channels. before castin to  `uint8`, I cast firstly to `double` , because i will use it in `imsubtract` to subtract with result of median filter in order to get a salient pixel

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't answer the question of the range of the values. It would be better to use `im2double` and `im2uint8` when casting the values so that they're scaled properly.

Comment: If i understand your question , the rang of images is different, I have a RGB image in a visible range and another image in infrared range

Comment: I'm asking what `min(filtered1(:))` and `max(filtered1(:))` are.

Comment: This gives this range [0.0784 , 0.8658]

Comment: That sounds about right. From this I would expect `imshow(filtered1)` to work. Can you post your images?